# Use Javascript Sourcemaps to unminify call stacks in Application Insights Logs

Tags: javascript, logging, azure-application-insights, source-maps

As [it is possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/source-map-support) to configure Azure's Application Insights to use Javascript Sourcemaps to unminify call stacks on the end to end transaction page, I was wondering:

Is it also possible to use the uploaded sourcemaps in the Log feature to unminify call stacks? (see image below for example of the log of an exception)

I have already successfully uploaded the sourcemaps to a blob container and the container has been configured in Application Insights, but in the Logs (Application Insights > Monitoring > Logs), I cannot find a way to unminify javascript call stacks. Does such a feature exist?

[image: Minified call stack of an Javascript exception that I wish to unminify]

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You need to log the error as an exception, not a trace in your application.